# Child Class from MagicMock object has weird spec='str' and can't use or mock methods of the class

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest, python-unittest.mock, magicmock

When a class is created deriving from a MagicMock() object it has an unwanted spec='str'. Does anyone know why this happens? Does anyone know any operations that could be done to the MagicMock() object in this case such that it doesn't have the spec='str' or can use methods of the class?

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

a = MagicMock()

class b():
    @staticmethod
    def x():
        return 1

class c(a):
    @staticmethod
    def x():
        return 1
print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
print(a.x())
print(b.x())
print(c.x())
```

which returns

```
MagicMock id='140670188364408'>
<class '__main__.b'>
<MagicMock spec='str' id='140670220499320'>
<MagicMock name='mock.x()' id='140670220574848'>
1
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/xyz/test.py", line 19, in <module>
        print(c.x())
    File "/xyz/lib/python3.7/unittest/mock.py", line 580, in _getattr_
        raise AttributeError("Mock object has no attribute %r" % name)
AttributeError: Mock object has no attribute 'x'
```

Basically I need the AttributeError to not be here. Is there something I can do to 'a' such that c.x() is valid?

edit - the issue seems to be with _mock_add_spec in [mock.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.11/Lib/unittest/mock.py) still not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Why are you subclassing from an *instance* of `MagicMock` in your test?  What's the code under test look like?

Comment: @Samwise I am trying to mock everything from a few libraries (flask and tensorflow) using [this code](https://github.com/arrmansa/unittest-module-mocking/blob/main/test/mock_import.py). This mostly works, but leads to 1 error where flask.view.Methodview is replaced with <MagicMock name='mock.MethodView' id=123xyz >. This leads to subclassing from an instance of MagicMock in the code that is being tested. While this is not ideal, I think the code should still work.

Comment: I think you'd be better off using a more normal mock/patch pattern than using that dynamic pattern and then trying to jury-rig the mock to work as a superclass.  The code you posted probably wasn't meant to support inheriting from something that you're mocking out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python, classes are actually instances of the `type` class. A `class` statement like this:

```
class c(a):
    @staticmethod
    def x():
        return 1
```

is really syntactic sugar of calling [`type`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type) with the name of the class, the base classes and the class members:

```
c = type('c', (a,), {'x': staticmethod(lambda: 1)})
```

The above statement would go through the given base classes and call the `__new__` method of the type of the first base class with the `__new__` method defined, which in this case is `a`. The return value gets assigned to `c` to become a new class.

Normally, `a` would be an actual class--an instance of `type` or a subclass of `type`. But in this case, `a` is not an instance of `type`, but rather an instance of `MagicMock`, so `MagicMock.__new__`, instead of `type.__new__`, is called with these 3 arguments.

And here lies the problem: `MagicMock` is not a subclass of `type`, so its `__new__` method is not meant to take the same arguments as `type.__new__`. And yet, when `MagicMock.__new__` is called with these 3 arguments, it takes them without complaint anyway because according to the [signature](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock) of `MagicMock`'s constructor (which is the same as `Mock`'s):

> ```
> class unittest.mock.Mock(spec=None, side_effect=None,
>     return_value=DEFAULT, wraps=None, name=None, spec_set=None,
>     unsafe=False, **kwargs)
> ```

`MagicMock.__new__` would assign the 3 positional arguments as `spec`, `side_effect` and `return_value`, respectively. As you now see, the first argument, the class name (`'c'` in this case), an instance of `str`, becomes `spec`, which is why your class `c` becomes an instance of `MagicMock` with a `spec` of `str`.

**The solution**

Luckily, a magic method named [`__mro_entries__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#resolving-mro-entries) was introduced since Python 3.7 that can solve this problem by providing a non-class base class with a substitute base class, so that when `a`, an instance of `MagicMock`, is used as a base class, we can use `__mro_entries__` to force its child class to instead use `a`'s class, `MagicMock` (or `SubclassableMagicMock` in the following example), as a base class:

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

class SubclassableMagicMock(MagicMock):
    def __mro_entries__(self, bases):
        return self.__class__,
```

so that:

```
a = SubclassableMagicMock()

class b():
    @staticmethod
    def x():
        return 1

class c(a):
    @staticmethod
    def x():
        return 1

print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
print(a.x())
print(b.x())
print(c.x())
```

outputs:

```
<SubclassableMagicMock id='140127365021408'>
<class '__main__.b'>
<class '__main__.c'>
<SubclassableMagicMock name='mock.x()' id='140127351680080'>
1
1
```

Demo: https://replit.com/@blhsing/HotAcademicCases

Comment: Thank you very much for the excellent explanation! I've been going over the code of mock.py and couldn't understand where/how the spec was being set.

Answer (score -2):

Interesting...

The issue you're facing is because the MagicMock object has a "spec" attribute, which only allows methods that are part of the specified object. In this case, the "spec" is set to "str", so only methods of the "str" class are allowed.

To resolve this, you can either create the MagicMock object without a "spec" attribute, or set the "spec" attribute to "None", which will allow all methods:

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock

a = MagicMock(spec=None)  # or a = MagicMock()

class b():
    @staticmethod
    def x():
        return 1

class c(a):
    @staticmethod
    def x():
        return 1

print(a)
print(b)
print(c)
print(a.x())
print(b.x())
print(c.x())
```

This should allow the "c.x()" method to be called without raising an "AttributeError". Also be careful of misconfigured mocks!

Comment: Hi. The code you posted does not work for me on python 3.7. If this worked for you could you please let me know what version you are using? Thanks.