# Can I inherit variable (class object) to a class in python?

Tags: python, class, pyqt

I followed PyQT Tutorial step by step.

Designing style is that UI design was made in desinger and I import UI code in python.

I'd like to ask a question about python class syntax because i can't find it when i search for it.

My qustion is that is it possible to inherit variable in python class.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

form_class = uic.loadUiType("C:\\PyQT tutorial\\1.Hello pyQT\\notepad.ui")[0]

class WindowClass(QMainWindow, form_class):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
```

In line 7, class WindowClass(QMainWindow, form_class)

I can't understand why variable **form_class** is there.

I think that only class name can be in parentheses.

QMainWindow is class name. however, form_class is variable.

And when i print type form_class and form_class.mro()

```
print(type(form_class))
print(type(form_class.mro()))
```

this is output

```
<class 'type'>

<class 'list'>
```

I hope you can resolve this issue as I am stuck.

Comment: It's impossible to make sense of the question, because there are many places where you are using a word and seem to think it means something different from what it actually means.

Comment: `form_class` is a **class**, just as `QMainWindow` is a class.  `WindowClass` inherits from **both** of those classes.

Comment: Even though you assign to it, `form_class` is still a class, not a class instance.  You can freely assign classes to variables in Python.  For example, if you do `my_class = QMainWindow`, then you can do `class WindowClass(my_class, form_class):` and it will behave identically.

Comment: I believe you have some misunderstanding about references. In fact, at least in Python syntax, even `QMainWindow` is considered a variable. You're probably ignoring that because you're using wild imports, which is generally discouraged, but it's not technically wrong per se and doesn't change the overall context, especially if you remember that, in Python, "everything is an object", or, to be precise, "everything is an `object` type", and there is no type restriction. Try to change that to `from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow`. Now, think: is `QMainWindow` that different from `form_class`?

Comment: In most modern languages, "variables" are objects that are semantically considered as references to memory addresses, and they can also be "aliases" to other existing references; this is even more important in OOP. A "word" within some code (a sequence of characters that are normally alphanumerical) is just a pointer to a memory address, unless the language syntax reads it as something else (a known keyword, such as an operator). The language eventually parses it depending on its features, but the concept remains: a "variable" is not "the" object, nor its type, it's a *reference* to it.

Comment: I strongly urge you to take your time to read more about the basics of code programming semantics, and think about: 1. each language syntax; 2. how languages are eventually *compiled* (at runtime or not); 3. how languages and their compiled code eventually are interpreted and/or run. Remember that the characters in some code are not what the program actually runs, but just a high level representation of *humanly readable* text that will eventually be interpreted and finally executed. I also suggest you to read about [esoteric languages](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esoteric_programming_language).

Comment: @TomKarzes Thank you for reply. I understand what you mean. my_class = QMainWindow and my_class_2=QMainWindow() are different. right? my_class is same with QMainWindow class  and my_class_2 is instance of QMainWindow.

Comment: @musicamante Thank you for reply. u r right. I am not familiar with computer science syntax. You mean variable is just a reference to object type. right? So, '''form_class''' is not variable which reference to class instance type but reference to class type. So it can be used for class inheritance.

Comment: @JaeKwanKim No, a variable is just a *reference*. You can think of it as a physical address in real life: you can save "Bob's home" in your address book at "56, 2nd Street", but you have to consider the consequences of that. What if Bob moves to another home? What if his old home becomes a business that's part of a franchise ("a class")? Or if the city changes the street name? To what a reference it actually references is irrelevant: it's just an address (a pointer) to an object in memory, which may or may not exist, it could be an instance, a class, a type: even *nothing* or an address error.

Comment: @JaeKwanKim `QMainWindow` is the class itself.  `QMainWindow()` is a newly created instance of that class.  Normally, you define a class once, then call that class to create instances of that class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All classes are objects/instances of type `type` in Python. `QMainWindow` is just a name that references a `type` object. You can freely assign the object reference to more names such as `form_class`, and it will behave identically to the name `QMainWindow`.

Comment: Thank you for clear answer. I want to ask one more question. According to your reply, we can only inherit object of type 'type' right?

Comment: @JaeKwanKim No, you can virtually inherit from *anything*. And, in reality, `QMainWindow` does not just reference a `type` object, it references an object that *finally* inherits from `type`. The class inheritance finally *inherits* from what the base object(s) inherit. This still doesn't change what a *reference* (a "variable", if you want) actually refers to, which is what standard languages use as an abstract item that refers to a memory pointer in order to allow human readable access to those objects.

Comment: @JaeKwanKim A class can inherit from any object as long as a base in its MRO has a `__new__` method defined to take as arguments a string of name, a tuple of bases and a dict of members. But if the object inherited by a "class" is not of type `type`, the "class" will not be technically considered as a "class" by some built-in functions such as `isinstance`, which is hard-coded in C to check if the second argument is an instance of `type`.

Comment: @JaeKwanKim I previously answered a question with such a use case, which you may find relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75439401/child-class-from-magicmock-object-has-weird-spec-str-and-cant-use-or-mock-met

Comment: @JaeKwanKim This is also relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76989290/how-to-fool-issubclass-checks-with-a-magicmock

Comment: @blhsing Thank you so much. what you recommended to read is very helpful. You mean class can inherit any object because not only type 'type' but also other type can have __new__method. however, other type __new__method is not appropriate for making subclass. right?

Comment: You're welcome. Python is a [duck typing language](https://machinelearningmastery.com/duck-typing-python/), so objects that provide the same interface as a class can be used as a class for inheritance (although as mentioned, it would fail to pass hard-coded type checks of certain built-in functions). So while it is generally inappropriate to inherit from a non-class object, it still can prove to be useful for very specific purposes as demonstrated in the aforementioned use case of making a `Mock` object subclassable.

Comment: @blhsing Yes I got it. Thank you so much.  you extend my understanding python.

Answer (score 0):

> I can't understand why variable **form_class** is there.

In the code presented, `form_class` is an in-scope identifier.  Python doesn't really draw distinctions among identifiers based on what kind of objects they identify, and in Python, everything is an object.

Python supports multiple inheritance.  In your code, this ...

> ```
> class WindowClass(QMainWindow, form_class):
> ```

... declares  a class in the current module whose identifier is `WindowClass`, and whose base classes are given by `QMainWindow` and `form_class`.

> I think that only class name can be in parentheses.

Approximately true.  The names in the parentheses must identify classes, and the code presented will fail at runtime if `form_class` does not identify a class when the `WindowClass` definition is executed. But `uic.loadUiType()` sounds promising for a function that returns a class object.  And I presume you're asking because it in fact works, which it very well might.

> `QMainWindow` is class name.

Yes, and one that has been `import`ed into the current module, therefore it can serve, unqualified, as an identifier that class.

> however, form_class is variable.

By which I take you to mean that it is *not* a class name, and you are probably right.  But you must be careful here to distinguish between *the identifier* and *the object it identifies*.  You could try inserting a `print(type(form_class))` and `dir(form_class)` into the module, and perhaps poking around a bit more.  I think you will find that the object it identifies is indeed a class.

This is why earlier I called your claim only approximately true.  In a class definition, the list of base classes must, of course, specify only classes.  In the vast majority of cases, they are specified via a qualified or unqualified version of the class's name, leveraging the fact that a class definition puts the class name in the declaring module's dictionary, referencing the class.  But any other expression specifying the class can be used just as well, and that's what you're seeing.

If you're more familiar with classes in Java or C++, for example, then it may help to bear in mind that Python's class definitions are not like those languages'.  Java and C++ class definitions are fundamentally declarative. Python class definitions are fundamentally functional: they have their effect by being *executed* in the context in which they appear.

Comment: Thank you so much..... your reply is very helpful. you mean form_class is not identifier( class name) however, object form_class identifies is class!!! right?  thank you so much.

Comment: @JaeKwanKim, the identifier `form_class` refers to a class, but it is not the *name* of that class in the sense of the value of its `__name__` attribute.  You could achieve a similar effect by assigning `another_class = QMainWindow`.  (As distinguished from `a_window = QMainWindow()`).

Answer (score 0):

The existing answers properly point out semantic and conceptual aspects, but I want to add a further point.
As simple and probably stupid as it looks, it probably helps to understand the simplicity of the issue.

The premise is this:

> I think that only class name can be in parentheses.
>
> QMainWindow is class name. however, form_class is variable.

And the following initial code:

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

form_class = uic.loadUiType("C:\\PyQT tutorial\\1.Hello pyQT\\notepad.ui")[0]
```

Now, let's get dirty:

```py
Whatever = QMainWindow
```

Is `Whatever` a "variable"? Yes!

So, what about this?

```py
class WindowClass(Whatever, form_class):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
```

Is `Whatever` a "class name"? No. It's a *reference* to a *class type*. Just like `form_class` is.

And that's another important reason for proper code syntax; especially in Python (but that's valid for most languages), object references have no absolute syntax except for the syntax requirements of the language (for instance, you cannot create names that start with a number); so you can name everything as you like.

Don't consider the *type* of objects only based on their syntax, but consider *naming* those objects based on their types.

For instance, while your `uic.loadUiType()` syntax isn't conceptually wrong, it semantically is, at least for proper code readability and maintenance, which are the only ways we, as humans, have to understand code context.

The following line:

```py
form_class = uic.loadUiType("C:\\PyQT tutorial\\1.Hello pyQT\\notepad.ui")[0]
```

Should become this:

```py
Form_Class = uic.loadUiType("C:\\PyQT tutorial\\1.Hello pyQT\\notepad.ui")[0]
^^^^^^^^^^

class WindowClass(QMainWindow, Form_Class):
                               ^^^^^^^^^^
```

While that doesn't change absolutely nothing at runtime, it *does* change a lot in the semantics of code readability and comprehension; therefore, also for maintenance and debugging.